# What's "come to doing something"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, verb-usage

[source](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page23.shtml)

The context is:

> Practise, practise, practise. There's an expression in English. If you don't want to lose it, use it. This is very true when it **comes to learning** foreign languages.

What does the bolded phrase mean? ***come to doing something***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase [**when it comes to something**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/when+it+comes+to) is an expression so widely used in everyday English that you're just literally going to hear it used all the time. And it simply means this:

> speaking about something or regarding something

Example sentences:

> **When it comes to learning English**, ELL is the best website on the Internet! (*Regarding learning English, ELL is the best website on the Internet!*)
>
> **When it comes to soccer**, Brazil is the best! (*Regarding soccer, Brazil is the best!*)

Your passage can be paraphrased like this:

> Practise, practise, practise. There's an expression in English. If you don't want to lose it, use it. **This is very true regarding learning foreign languages.**

Comment: "When it comes to that, we can lend you the fare" (an example from the link you gave) = "When we can lend you the fare, we can lend you the fare" or "As the fare is concerned, we can lend you the fare" or "Regarding the borrower is you, we can lend you the fare"? Which one?

Comment: @ZhangJian *Regarding that, we can lend you the fare* is how you should understand it, I think.